# Webstorm: Auto-completion still not working with LODASH (and others) after installing DefinitelyTyped

Tags: webstorm, lodash, definitelytyped

Using Webstorm 11.0.3 and Lodash 4.3.0. I have installed loadash [`DefinitelyTyped`](http://definitelytyped.org) (see picture at the bottom) but am still not getting auto-completion for:

```
_.has
```

Do I need to do anything other than downloading and installing the `DefinitelyTyped` package as global?

TIA!

[image]

Comment: Here's are the completion results that I get when lodash definitely typed package is enabled: http://i.imgur.com/1XUMMaD.png?1 Do you have the same?

Comment: @EkaterinaPrigara, yes there is a "has" in the auto-completion list. But even though that I choose it, Webstorm still gives me a warning about "unresolved function og method has()". So I am thinking the "has" in the autocomplete list is related to something else than the Loadash method "_.has" .... ?

Comment: I also managed to install lodash but my functions assigned with lodash dont get resolved either. Did you find a solution yet ?

Comment: @rabbitco - What's odd is, WebStorm's intellisense does not pick up the lodash symbols during code editing.  But when you enter the lodash symbol (_) into the debugger console at runtime, it *does* offer the lodash methods as auto-complete choices!  Sadly, it doesn't recognize the lodash object and says it's undefined when you try to evaluate an object using it.  A mixed bag of strange.

Comment: any updates? still having this in 2020